# How do they do this w.l.o.g. so freely (Fourier series).

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Theorem 2.1.  Suppose that $f$ is an integrable function on the circle with $\hat{f}(n) = 0$ for all $n \in  \mathbb{Z}$. Then $f(\theta_0) = 0$ whenever $f$ is continuous at the
>   point $\theta_0$.
>
> *Proof*. We suppose first that f is real-valued, and argue by contradiction. Assume, without loss of generality, that $f$ is defined on the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$.

I won't get why this w.l.o.g. works until I finish the proof and can check that it works, but are there any insights beforehand I could have regarding this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $f$ is defined on the circle.  That means that $f=f(e^{i\theta})$, where $\theta$ is an angle ranging around the circle.

There are many ranges that you could use for $\theta$: $[0,2\pi],[-2\pi,0],[1,1+2\pi]$, but these are all essentially equivalent (note, for example that the theorem says nothing about the parametrization of $\theta$) and it's easier just to choose one - say, $[-\pi,\pi]$.

Comment: Please see my edits.  I think I've found a solution

Comment: @EnjoysMath If you've found an answer to your question, you can add it as an answer down here to help people learn, but you shouldn't put the answer in the body of your question.  If you do that, it's likely to get closed.

Answer (score 1):

I know that if $f$ is defined instead on $[a,b]$, then there's an invertible line $\ell(x) = (b-a)x/(2\pi) + (b+a)/2$ such that $g(x) = f(\ell(x))$, $g$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$ and $f(x) = g(\ell^{-1}(x))$.  Also, $\ell$ is a diffeomorphism and a homeomorphism.

Let $f$ be defined on $[a,b]$.  Then $\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) e^{-2\pi i n x/(b-a)} dx$.  And if $g(x) = f(\ell(x))$ is defined on $[-\pi, \pi]$, then $\hat{g}(n) = \frac{1}{\pi - (-\pi)} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g(x) e^{- 2 \pi i n x / (2 \pi)}dx = \\ \frac{1}{\ell^{-1}(b) - \ell^{-1}(a)} \int_{\ell^{-1}(a)}^{\ell^{-1}(b)} f(\ell(x)) e^{- 2 \pi i n x / (\ell^{-1}(b) - \ell^{-1}(a))} dx $.

Making the substitution $u = \ell(x)$ we have $du = d\ell/dx = (b-a)/(2\pi)$ so if in the integral we can perform your standard $u,du$ substitution, then we have that $\hat{g}(n) = \frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(u) e^{-2 \pi i n \ell^{-1}(u)/(2\pi)} du$.

The exponent of $e$ in the last integrand is $- in \frac{(2\pi u - (b+a)\pi)}{b-a}$.

So $\hat{g}(n) = \frac{(-1)^{n \frac{-(b+a)}{b-a}}}{b-a}\int_a^b f(u) e^{-2 \pi i n u / (b-a)} du$.

In other words a reparametrization of the interval over which $f$ is defined yields coefficients that are constant multiples of the original coefficients of $f$ before the interval is reparameterized.  So re-examining the theorem, there exists a reparameterization to $[-\pi, \pi]$, $g$, of $f$ such that $\hat{f}(n) = 0$ iff $\hat{g}(n) = 0$.  So when we prove the thoerem over $[-\pi, \pi]$, then we've proved it over all intervals $[a,b]$.

*Proof*.  The theorem goes "if $\hat{f}(n) = 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $f(\theta_0)= 0$ whenever $f$ is continuous at the point $\theta_0$."  If $g = f\circ\ell$ is a reparameterization and we've prove the theorem for $g$.  Then we've proved that "if $\hat{f}(n) = 0, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $f(\ell(\theta_0)) = 0$ at continuity points $\theta_0$."  The last part is the same as "$f(\phi_0) = 0$ at continuity points $\phi_0 = \ell(\theta_0)$", since if $f\circ \ell$ is continuous at $\theta_0$, and any open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is the inverse image of some open set in $\mathbb{R}$ under homeomorphism $\ell$, $f$ is continuous at $\phi_0$. Conversely, if $f$ is continuous at some $\phi_0$ then there's $\theta_0$ such that $f\circ\ell$ is continuous at $\theta_0$.  I think that proves it.  QED.